# aspx : ListView in a ListView with ID from a database

Tags: asp.net, database, listview

I'm quite a beginner in aspx but I want to use a ListView with a ListView inside. Multiple ListView contained inside the first one will have their ID from a database. I have multiple problems but first : Is it possible ? If yes, can anyone explain me how and why my code doesn't work ? Here is my aspx code :

```
<asp:ListView ID="gvBureaux" runat="server"> <!-- first ListView -->
            <ItemTemplate>
                <div class="content__item" data-space='<%# Eval("Space_Bureau") %>' data-category='<%# Eval("Category_Bureau") %>'> <!-- this works-->
                    <h3 class="content__item-title"><%# Eval("Label_Bureau") %></h3> <!-- this works-->
                    <asp:ListView ID='<%# Eval("Code_Bureau") %>' runat="server"> <!-- error -->
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <!-- this works-->
                            <div class="col-md-2">
                                <div class="product">
                                    <div class="product__info">
                                        <img class="product__image" src='<%# Eval("Photo") %>' alt="Product 1" />
                                        <a href='skype:<%# Eval("Coll_Skype") %>?chat' class='<%# Eval("Coll_Skype") != null ? "" : "hide" %>'><i class="fa fa-lg fa-skype"></i></a>
                                        <a href='mailto:<%# Eval("Coll_Mail") %>' class='<%# Eval("Coll_Mail") != null ? "" : "hide" %>'><i class="fa fa-lg fa-envelope-o"></i></a>
                                        <h3 class="product__title"><%# Eval("NomPrenomCapitalize") %></h3>
                                        <span class="product__price highlight"><%# Eval("CompetencesTrombi") %></span>
                                        <i class='fa fa-lg fa-phone'><%# Eval("Coll_Fixe") %></i>
                                        <i class='fa fa-lg fa-mobile-phone'><%# Eval("Coll_Port") %></i>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <!-- /this works-->
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:ListView>
                </div>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:ListView>
```

And my code behind:

```
gvBureaux.DataSource = M_Bureau.GetListeBureau();
        gvBureaux.DataBind();
        var Bureaux = M_Bureau.GetListeBureau();
        ListView listView = new ListView();

        foreach (Bureau Br in Bureaux)
        {
            var collaborateurs = M_Collaborateur.GetCollaborateursByidBureau(Br.ID_Bureau);
            listView.DataSource = collaborateurs;
            listView.DataBind();
        }
```

Thanks !

Comment: You should ask focused questions on stackoverflow. If you have something like *"I have multiple problems such as [...]"* it's almost certainly a bad question because it is actually multiple questions packed into one text.

Comment: edited : better ?

Comment: How it doesn't work? What error you are getting? The inside listview will have different data based on the item of the main listview?

Comment: My main error is that you can't use an eval as the ID of the ListView.
The inside ListView will have different item but this already work. Before, I had a lot of Listview based on the same structure so I just wanted to generate all those ListView with a ListView of ListViews

Comment: You should probably try to utilize the `DataKeyNames` property of `ListView` instead of trying to evaluate the `ID` property.

Comment: @grek40 i tried to use DataKeyNames but I don't really understood how it works

Comment: Thats why the smart guys at microsoft wrote some documentation. Read it, try it, read it again, try again, ask remaining questions.

Comment: Well thanks @grek40 ! I didn't think about it ! (ironic) The fact is that I don't usually use datasourceID directly in the ListView tag but in a cs script "behind" my aspx script. And the example is way too specific and too far from what I use for the rest of my app.

Comment: In fact, you have not provided any code that tries to use the ID value at all. So you are the only one who knows what the ID will be needed for later.

Comment: Before, my ListView had (for example) "abc" as ID and in my cs code, I had
    abc.DataSource = collaborateurs;
    abc.DataBind();
But I had this for 28 ListView based on the same structure.

Comment: You can probably use the `ItemDataBound` event on the outer listview in order to assign the items source of the inner listview.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution to construct nested lists using the `ItemDataBound` event.

I use some data structures and generators for demonstration, replace them by your queries as needed:

```
public class InnerListItem
{
    public string InnerItemTitle { get; set; }
}

public class OuterListItem
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string ListTitle { get; set; }
}

private List<OuterListItem> GetOuterList(int listsCount)
{
    var result = new List<OuterListItem>();
    for (int i = 0; i < listsCount; i++)
    {
        result.Add(new OuterListItem
        {
            Id = i + 1,
            ListTitle = string.Format("List {0}", i + 1)
        });
    }
    return result;
}
private List<InnerListItem> GetInnerList(int id, int innerItemCount)
{
    var result = new List<InnerListItem>();
    for (int i = 0; i < innerItemCount; i++)
    {
        result.Add(new InnerListItem
        {
            InnerItemTitle = string.Format("Item {0}.{1}", id, i + 1)
        });
    }
    return result;
}
```

The ASPX example:

```
<asp:ListView ID="outerList" OnItemDataBound="outerList_ItemDataBound" runat="server">
    <LayoutTemplate>
        <ul>
            <li id="itemPlaceholder" runat="server" />
        </ul>
    </LayoutTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <li>
            <label><%# Eval("ListTitle") %></label>
            <asp:ListView ID="innerList" runat="server">
                <LayoutTemplate>
                    <ol>
                        <li id="itemPlaceholder" runat="server" />
                    </ol>
                </LayoutTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <li>
                        <span><%# Eval("InnerItemTitle") %></span>
                    </li>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:ListView>
        </li>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:ListView>
```

The initialization and the event function to start the inner list binding

```
protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var outerItems = GetOuterList(2);
    outerList.DataSource = outerItems;
    outerList.DataBind();
}

protected void outerList_ItemDataBound(object sender, ListViewItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item.ItemType == ListViewItemType.DataItem)
    {
        var innerList = e.Item.FindControl("innerList") as ListView;
        var listObject = e.Item.DataItem as OuterListItem;
        var innerItems = GetInnerList(listObject.Id, 3);
        innerList.DataSource = innerItems;
        innerList.DataBind();
    }
}
```

Should be possible to transform the sample for your actual data case.

Comment: Thanks ! It was a bit hard to transform it but it works ! Thanks a lot !